# Having trouble splitting up Django models into separate files

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to split up my Django models into separate files but I apparently haven't done it right. When I try to run my Django script that I've been using without problems since I started my project, I get this:

```
$ ./import.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mcif.models import GenericImport, CSVRow
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_address import AccountAddress
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/account_address.py", line 1, in <module>
    class AccountAddress(models.Model):
NameError: name 'models' is not defined
```

My app is called `mcif` and it's talking about `mcif/models/account_address.py` which is this:

```
class AccountAddress(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'account_address'
        app_name = 'mcif'
```

It's saying it doesn't know about the `models` part of `AccountAddress(models.Model)`, which makes sense. I'm assuming I need to import something, but if that's the case, I don't know what to import. If that's not the case, I'm at a total loss. What should I do?

Comment: When you read this, what did you notice about the `import`? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#quick-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any `from django.db import models` in account_address.py?